# How to parse Azure Search response in PHP?

Tags: php, rest, azure, azure-cognitive-search

Currently I try Azure Search.

I managed to insert documents in the index, and now I want to parse my result.

My code looks like this:

```
<?php
$url ="";
   $url .="https://mywebsite.search.windows.net/indexes/test/docs";
   $url .= "?search=";
   $url .= $keyword;
   $url .= "&api-version=2014-07-31-Preview";
   print $url;


   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
           'api-key: mytoken',
           'Accept: application/json',
     ));

   $data = curl_exec($ch);

   if (curl_errno($ch)) {
   print "Error: " . curl_error($ch);
   } else 
   {
   // Show me the result
   print var_dump($data);
   curl_close($ch);
   }
?>
```

My program works fine, but I can't parse my result who look like this:

> string(633)
>   "{"@odata.context":"https://mywebsite.search.windows.net/indexes('adventurehotel')/$metadata#docs(hotelId,baseRate,description,hotelName,category,tags,parkingIncluded,smokingAllowed,lastRenovationDate,rating,location)","value":[{"@search.score":0.16137227,"hotelId":"1","baseRate":199.0,"description":"Best
>   hotel in town","hotelName":"Fancy
>   Stay","category":"Luxury","tags":["pool","view","wifi","concierge"],"parkingIncluded":false,"smokingAllowed":false,"lastRenovationDate":"2010-06-27T00:00:00Z","rating":5,"location":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-122.131577,47.678581],"crs":{"type":"name","properties":{"name":"EPSG:4326"}}}}]}"

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you encode the data in the first place?  Looks like a JSON string

Comment: Just `json_decode` it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just **[json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)** it, it is just a **[json](http://www.json.org/)** string.

`json_decode`, if called with `true` as the second parameter, will give you an associative [array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) representation of the string you want to parse. The string itself should be a valid `json` string, or you will get `null` as the function result.

Take note, that as of php 5.5 and higher, json extension should be installed separately of the main php install due to its license.

Comment: thanks you for your answer.

if someone wants to decode it, follow this example:
$json_decoded = json_decode($data, true);
print $json_decoded['value']['0']['category'];